# what after the basic c++?

Tags: c++

i studied basics of c++ in college, we used the book object oriented programming in c++ by robert lafore.

i studied till pointers (almost half the book) and i still feel outdated using the console and not doing something other than that (forgive me for my ignorance) i want to do windows simple apps and knowing how to employ the little i learned.

the problem is when i open a win32 project  in Visual studio for example it opens a lot of stuffs and many .cpp's and .h's .

is there a way to comprehend that and walking on the right path?

the code is complicated to me and mind teasing is it suppose to be like this ?intended to be like this for beginners ?  is there a reliable tutorial to introduce me to that or do i need to learn the advanced concepts of c++ like templates and virtual functions and file i\o or they are not necessery ?

thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure it's the answer you seek for and that's why it's a comment: C++ gives you "lower" access, in terms that you can touch elements of programming (whatever) that other languages would limit you on. If you're just into developing apps with visual interface and wants a quicker "design & code" then I suggest you try C#. It's very similar to C++. If you want to go lower, and have greater control over what you're building then stick with C++. Learning inheritance for example will lead you to virtual functions no matter how complicated it sounds like (actally it's a simple subject).

Comment: By the way, the below link is great if you decide to go with C++, something that I personally very recommend, both because it'll give you better insight over programming in general and because it's just funnier. The link: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: thanks for the link, i actully have a purpose to learn c++.because it is required for 3d and game development, but i guess i should work on my geometry,trignometry and aother math skills...:(

Comment: The right path would be learning another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are simpler languages to learn programming in then C++, and less complicated concepts to be mastered in simple CLI applications.  In fact, using C++ to write GUI software is probably one of the hardest things to learn to do well.  If you are intent on learning only visual programming, and only in C++, then I suggest trying the programming toolkit QT (http://developer.qt.nokia.com/resources/getting_started/) as you will have a window on the screen faster and more logically then nearly anything else.

Otherwise, pick nearly any interpreted (VB, Python, Ruby) or quasi-compiled (Perl, Java, C#) language and work through a command line tutorial first, as your progress will be much more likely.

Comment: when you said c++ only and visual programming, i actully have other plans like learning direct x API and else, this actully in-years plan, so will learning and programming with c# (or another languages) is going to distract me from my goals or will help me to achieve the proverb ( hitting two birds(birds=programming languages in this case more than two birds maybe) by one stone)

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty project in Visual Studio, then it won't create a bunch of .cpp and .h files that you don't care about.

After that, to learn how to write a windows application from scratch, read *Programming Windows* by Charles Petzold, or google a windows programming tutorial on the web.

Later, get books by Jeff Richter (*Windows via C/C++*) to learn more advanced windows programming concepts.

Answer (score 1):

win32/Visual Studio  is not a good way to learn GUI programming --Visual Studio generates too many mysterious and unreadable pieces of code and the win32 API is a C API which carries a lot baggage from from the early versions of windows.

It would be much better to use a more organised and conceptualy cleaner framework like Qt or WxWidgets to learn GUI programming.

I would actually recommend you use wxPython to learn the basics of wX and switch to the c++ interface when you have a good understanding of the widgets etc.

Most of the c++ code you need for a GUI is just boiler plate property setting and exception handling which wont teach you much and is pretty tedious.

Comment: win32 doesn't generate anything. Unless you use a generator, like Qt or WxWidgets. Both of which are more likely to "generate too many mysterious and unreadable pieces of code", hiding what's really going on underneath.

Comment: I agree, Win32 doesn't generate anything. However it is a pretty nasty way to do a GUI, especially for someone who hasn't done all that much C++ before (especially being that winapi is a C api that he'll try to use with OO C++). I think something like WTL would be a lot better off than Win32.

Comment: Oops I meant Visual Studio C++!

Answer (score 1):

My tip on getting a hang of windows programming:
Read [The Forgers tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/).

Instead of choosing a project with stuff in it, just choose a blank project and start from scratch, it's actually *not that hard* once you get the hang of it. However, a basic Win32 program consists of approximately 70-100 lines, because:

- You have to set up a unique window (this includes registering your window in Windows and creating it correctly)
- You have to *handle* all the messages that are sent to your window
- You have to *react* to the messages that are sent to your window

Especially check out [the Simple Window](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/simple_window.html) that TheForger created, then start fideling with the flags (dwExStyle and dwStyle) in [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680(VS.85).aspx), check out the wndProc function and see what the [messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468922(VS.85).aspx) are (I think the most interesting you should focus on is WM_CREATE, WM_PAINT and WM_SIZE). Hopefully, after some time you will get a feel for what everything is and how it interacts.

It takes some time but I guess most stuff in programming does if you want to learn it. When you have your basic knowledge of a window, you should probably see how you should move on, if you should start with 3D (DirectX or OpenGL) or stay with 2D (GDI+). Or take up Qt like suggested by [James Anderson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252876/what-after-the-basic-c/4252948#4252948), it really depends on what you want to do. But I do think that you should take that decision **then** and not now. StackOverflow will most likely assist if you ask what direction you should take if you know what kind of a project you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start somewhere.  So yes, you need to learn all those things you mentioned and then some.  The then some includes writing console apps until you really understand whats going on.  The only reason I can speak is because I am in a similar boat.  I would say, from the sound of it, that I am probably more "advanced" than you and I still find doing some assignments/projects in the console challenging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: Windows and stuff is *complicated*, you have all these events (clicks, keys, mouse stuff etc) and you are interacting heavily with the operating system. It is good that you start with console apps, because there you can focus on the actual programming, i.e., learning how to use loops, functions, classes etc.

To learn how to make windows, you should absolutely understand what classes are and how to use them, because in my opinion, all window toolkits worth learning make use of classes.

So, how does this windows stuff work? The good news: A lot of work has already been done. No need for you to re-program a "print file"-dialogue, no need to hand-draw windows with their symbols and menus etc. This is all readily available in so-called frameworks, and there is a bunch of them out there. You can use the Microsoft Foundation Classes (MFC), or Nokia's Qt or wxWidgets etc.

Google for tutorials on these, and this should get you on the way. First look around which framework looks best to you and then do the Hello World examples.

Once you gain some experience, you'll see that it isn't THAT scary. The only scary thing is the unknown that is yet to be conquered.

(A more gentle introduction would be to first do Java/Swing as I find this VERY easy, but the C++ alternatives aren't too hard, really)

Answer (score 0):

Just play around visual studio if you want to get familiar with Visual studio or any IDE. VS does lots of things on behalf of you. Its interactive, select one option, look into auto generated files .h or .cpp, compile it. If you get any error google it. I myself learned this way.

For learning C++ lafore is good book to start with. The most important way of learning any language is writing lots of code. Dont get tempted to look solution in book. The best way is:

> ```
> a) Read the problem properly 
> b) Write your logic on paper first
> c) Identify interfaces
> d) Convert your logic into programme
> e) Compile it
> f) remove the errors
> g) remove all the warnings
> ```